# RxJS: How to prevent clicks on a element when using drag n drop

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say i have this simple code for drag n drop via RxJS:

```
const { fromEvent } = Rx.Observable;
const target = document.querySelector('.box');

const mouseup = fromEvent(target, 'mouseup');
const mousemove = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
const mousedown = fromEvent(target, 'mousedown');

document.getElementById("click")
.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert('clicked');
})

const mousedrag = mousedown.selectMany((md) => {
  const startX = md.clientX + window.scrollX,
        startY = md.clientY + window.scrollY,
        startLeft = parseInt(md.target.style.left, 10) || 0,
        startTop = parseInt(md.target.style.top, 10) || 0;
  md.preventDefault();
  return mousemove.map((mm) => {
    mm.preventDefault();
    return {
      left: startLeft + mm.clientX - startX,
      top: startTop + mm.clientY - startY
    };
  }).takeUntil(mouseup);
});

const subscription = mousedrag.subscribe((pos) => {
  target.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
  target.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
});
```

And simple html

```
<div class="box">
  <a id="click">Click test</a>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gerasalus/pen/QKbYaQ)

Now if you click and drag the box it drags ok. But if you click on "Click test" and drag it, it drags ok, but after you stop dragging, alert is shown. How to avoid this?

`preventDefault` does not work, since we clicked on child. 
`stopPropagation` would not also work, because we would stop propagation up, but the alert click handler is on child of the box

Answer (score 1):

`mousedown` and `click` are two different events. AFAIK you cannot stop one from within the other. But you could for example set a specific class name in your rx code and test against this class in the click handler. On the `mouseup` event you can then remove the class again. Since this event is called before the `click` event handler can take place I've used `setTimeout` to put it back on the event loop. If you have a better idea of how this can be done, let me know.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oar2jgeo/) (written in RxJS 5).

Full code:

```
const { fromEvent } = Rx.Observable;
const target = document.querySelector('.box');

const mouseup = fromEvent(target, 'mouseup');
const mousemove = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
const mousedown = fromEvent(target, 'mousedown');

document.getElementById("click")
  .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('rx-drag')) {
        alert('clicked');
    }
  });

const mousedrag = mousedown.mergeMap((md) => {
  const startX = md.clientX + window.scrollX,
        startY = md.clientY + window.scrollY,
        startLeft = parseInt(md.target.style.left, 10) || 0,
        startTop = parseInt(md.target.style.top, 10) || 0;

  md.target.classList.add('rx-drag');
  md.preventDefault();
  return mousemove.map((mm) => {
    mm.preventDefault();
    return {
      left: startLeft + mm.clientX - startX,
      top: startTop + mm.clientY - startY
    };
  }).takeUntil(mouseup.do(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        md.target.classList.remove('rx-drag');
    });
  }));
});

const subscription = mousedrag.subscribe((pos) => {
  target.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
  target.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
});
```

Comment: works, but basically it's a hack (what if i have 4-5 a tags which are in different components) :/  My idea was to add a hook to document click event with useCapture and then either use preventDefault() and stopPropogation if there was mouse move event, or cancel it. But i did'nt manage to make it work.